# Website localization depending on domain extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, web-config

I'm currently building my personal website in ASP.Net MVC and I want **two versions**: a French and an English one.

I've got **two domain names** and I want to match the English version to the "**.com**" domain and the French version to the "**.fr**" domain:

- When you go to www.mywebsite.fr, you will get the French version
- When you go to www.mywebsite.com, you will get the English version

So, my question is: What is the recommended way to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick overview: use [ASP.NET Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx) infrastructure to enable localization (there's [plenty of stuff](http://blog.eworldui.net/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC---Localization.aspx) for localizing ASP.NET MVC-based sites) and add section to your `Web.config` that would map `.com` to `en-US`, and `.fr` to `fr-Whatever`.

Comment: Hi, I know it's a very old thread but I am currently trying to do the same, but I can not find any documents on how to map for example .com to en-US and .se to sv-SE in web.config. Can you point me to a starting point please?